# SharePoint On-line Dependencies on Exchange Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, exchange, exchange-online

We recently signed agreement on o365. We are planning to kick of SharePoint on-line, yammer implementation project including migration from SharePoint on-prem.

But exchange on-line project will go live after SharePoint on-line implementation. In this regard we would like to know dependencies of SharePoint on-line, yammer on exchange on-line.

For example we came to know the following cannot be done configured without exchange on-line.

1) Adding custom tiles in app launcher

2) Site mailboxes

Thanks,

Praveen

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach to adding an app to App Launcher:
1. Office 365 Admin > Company Profile > Custom Tiles
2. From here its pretty straight forward

However each user will need to pin the app to their app launcher, you cannot push this to all users.

Exchange is used to store the Office 365 Profile picture, which appears on the top right when using Office 365 services. If exchange is not available I believe this defaults to SharePoint Profile.

Comment: Thank you. But we want to publish the app in launch globally. We are looking out for other dependencies.